# Math.Round not working when applied to a property

Tags: c#, properties, lambda, rounding

I am trying to round a decimal property which is being summed with a Lambda expression. But the rounding is not working. Here is my code:

```
        public decimal ActualWeight
    {
        get
        {
            decimal actual = 0;

            try
            {
               actual = Math.Round((from c in Containers select c.NetWeight).Sum());

            }
            catch
            {
                actual = 0;
            }

            return actual / (Constants.METRICTONS);
        }
    }
```

I have tried variations on this and nothing works. I am using Math.Round on the same value elsewhere in my app and it works like this:

```
tab2.Cell(1 + x, 5).Value = Math.Round(c.MetricTons, 3).ToString();
```

This works fine. Can someone tell me why my Math.Round method is not working correctly when applied to my lambda expression/property?

The correct rounded value I am looking for is 241.978.
But my broken math keeps returning 241.976.

Comment: `But the rounding is not working`. What do you mean? Is it lazy and refuse to work?

Comment: Looks to me like the data from Containers is a little different here than in other parts of the app.  Try assigning the result of .Sum() and comparing that to what you see in the "correct" parts of the program.

Comment: Can you provide sample values for `NetWeight` for you test scenario and the type of `NetWeight` (decimal? double? float?)

Comment: When you get a problem like this, break it up into multiple lines (put the sum it to its own var). Then single step the debugger to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following test case works as expected. The output is `28`.

```
List<decimal> Containers = new List<decimal> {Decimal.Parse("5.11"),
                                              Decimal.Parse("4.1"),
                                              Decimal.Parse("7.6"),
                                              Decimal.Parse("1.9"),
                                              Decimal.Parse("9.1")};
decimal actual = 0;
try
{
    actual = Math.Round((from c in Containers select c).Sum());
}
catch
{
    actual = 0;
}

Console.WriteLine(actual);
```

Therefore I think your issue may be in another piece of the code.